# Change words order function "error" C

Tags: c, linux

I'm doing a program in C that changes the line's order of a file, line by line. The problem  is that once I apply the function "change", it first prints a null line.

This is the code that works without reversing the first line of the file and commented is the line that replaces `fprintf( stdout, "%s", fgets(line, 2048, file));`

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <sysexits.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>


   char* change ( char *word ){
            int i;
            int j;
            char aux;
            for(i=0, j=strlen(word)-1 ; i<j ; i++, j--){
               aux=word[i];
               word[i]=word[j];
               word[j]=aux;
            }
                 return word;
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    char line[2048];
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    printf( "File: %s -> ", argv[1] );
    if( file )
    printf( "Exists (OPEN)\n" );
    else
    {
     printf( "Error (CAN'T OPEN)\n" );
      return 1;
    }

   printf( "The first line of the file: %s\n\n", argv[1] );
    /*fprintf( stdout, "%s", change(line) );*/
     fprintf( stdout, "%s", fgets(line, 2048, file)); 

   if( !fclose(file) )
    printf( "\nFile closed\n" );
    else
   {
     printf( "\nError: can't close \n" );
    return 1;
   }

   return 0;
   }
```

Suposing the file days.txt

```
   Monday
   Tuesday
   ...
```

With `fprintf( stdout, "%s", fgets(line, 2048, file));` it prints `Monday`, but with `fprintf( stdout, "%s", change(line) );` should print `yadnoM` but it prints a null line and I don't know why. (Note that i'm programming in Ubuntu)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before calling this fprintf( stdout, "%s", change(line));...you need to have something in your buffer line...without copying anything in 'line' you are passing this to change function

Comment: @SAN then, I should do `fgets(line, 2048, file)` before just to load the buffer?

Comment: Note that the newline is included

Comment: E.g `"Monday\n"` --> change() --> `"\nyadnoM"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't verify other part of your code..

But for this part....

Before calling this fprintf( stdout, "%s", change(line));...you have to copy data in buffer line from the file...without copying in 'line' you are passing this to change function

you should do like this

```
fprintf( stdout, "%s", fgets(line, 2048, file));
fprintf( stdout, "%s", change(line) );
```

or

```
fgets(line, 2048, file);
fprintf( stdout, "%s", change(line) );
```

Comment: The result is the same... It prints a null line before `yadnoM` and I changed all as you said

Comment: As @BLUEPIXY has also pointed out...This is because of new line '\n' also copied in fgets. Read this http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets

Comment: @marckamoedo you can put NULL in place of '\n' to remove this new line. Try this                                                      fgets(line, 2048, file);
 line[strlen(line)-1]='\0';
 fprintf( stdout, "%s", change(line) );

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when you run fgets() it reads the entire line including the new line character \n.

So when you run `change(fgets(line, 2048, file))` it is basically moves the \n to the beginning of the file, so you get one blank line.